# post to dynamically-created file

Tags: php, forms, dynamic-data

Our site creates files on-the-fly that present user-specified data to the world on the web.

There is in each such '_present.php' file a form that needs to post to itself -- only problem is, the file is created dynamically based on uploaded user data and the filename is also somewhat arbitrary.

Here's the process

```
 1) a 'standard' file called _present.php has a common form "TheForm" in it
 2) this file,  _present.php, is copied to Yf9iZ17a.php (for example) when 
      the user uploads data -- and from that point, Yf9iZ17a.php presents 
      that user's just-uploaded data
 3) and "TheForm" is inside this Yf9iZ17a.php, which again is just a copy of 
    _present.php, but modified to handle the user's just-uploaded data
```

Pretty simple. _present.php has "TheForm" inside it; the user uploads their data; we copy _present.php to a 
filename for that user's data.

The PROBLEM is -- we need TheForm to post to its own
filename, which is dynamically created.

In other words, this won't suffice:

```
 <form name="TheForm" method="post" action="_present.php">
```

However, this WOULD work:

```
  <form name="TheForm" method="post" action="Yf9iZ17a.php">
```

But we cannot hard-code the form's html with "Yf9iZ17a.php" because -- that filename is created 
dynamically, on-the-fly, at runtime.

This is one failure we have succeeded in executing:

```
     <form name="TheForm" method="post" action="<?php echo __FILE__ ;  ?>">
```

A 'View Page Source' sure enough proves that "php echo **FILE**" correctly echos the
full path (not relative path, the full path) to Yf9iZ17a.php.

Well that won't work.  Giving the browser the fully-qualified pathname to a file -- 
a file that is *on the server* -- well why would you WANT to do it in the first place unless
you're grasping at straws.  So that was a failure.

Surely this comes up, dynamically created filenames whose internal forms must post to those filenames --
what's the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this instead, perhaps?

```
<?php echo basename(__FILE__); ?>
```

Comment: That almost has it.  The problem is, each registered user gets a subfolder then their dynamically-created data files (based on _present.php) go in there, so basename() only works if the dynamically-created file is in the root folder of the site.  While our database keeps the relative path to the user's subfolders -- I would need to call a php function as the form's "action" and echo the return value of the php function call -- such as:  action="echo myPhpFuncToGetsubfolder . basename(__FILE__) or something.  Is it even possible to call a php function as the 'action=' of a form?

Comment: You may prune the __FILE__ absolute path just to the depth you need as well - or replace `<?php echo basename(__FILE__); ?>` with more complex expression, calculating the user sub-folder as well.

Comment: Yep it occurred to me, you brought up basename() and that's an example of calling a php function, I guess I should be able to call any function as my action="  "  in the form.  I'll just write a php function in _present.php that constructs the relative path to the file then echo the return value in my action=" "  on the form.  Thanks for your help.